# Different layout for orientation AND screen size - Android

Tags: android, layout, orientation, screen-size

I know you can specify a different layout file for orientation by creating a directory;
layout-land

And I know you can create another layout file for a large(tablet) screen size by creating a directory;
layout-large

My question is, can you create a directory that supports both? Something like;
layout-land-large

It's vital for a piece of work that a certain screen layout is displayed only on a tablet device in landscape mode, otherwise it's the default. If my solution isn't valid, is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the folder name to: `layout-large-land`

This link explains how provide resources for different configurations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html